# How to start soundplayer on MouseDown in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

When I trigger `soundPlayer.Play();` on the click event of a button it only plays after you unclick the button. I've tried to trigger it on MouseDown with

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    soundPlayer.Play();
}
```

But that didn't do anything. How can I make it work?

Edit: I figured it out, I did it by going into events under properties and using the MouseDown event

Comment: Is the mouse down function bound to the event or did you just paste in the function?

Comment: It works on my VS2017 .NET 4.6.1 AnyCPU Windows 10 x64

Comment: @John I just have this so probably not. How would I bind it?